# How many secret codes can be made by assigning each letter of the alphabet a (unique) different letter?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The letter A can be assigned in 26 ways
The letter B can be assigned in 25 ways
.
.
.
The letter Z can be assigned in 1 ways
So the answer is 26!
and in Euler constant form is $e^{61.26170}$

However, the answer in the text book is $≈ (26!)^2/e$

Could you please help me with this problem?

Comment: Your $26!$ would not ensure all the code letters different to their original letters.  $(26!)^2/e$ is even bigger so too large, though might have a typo.  You might want to investigate *derangements*

Comment: @coffeemath because $26!$ is squared in $(26!)^2/e$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the book is (implicitly or explicitly) looking for codes where a letter is *never* mapped onto itself. In other words, it is asking for the number of [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of 26 objects, which is approximately equal to $\frac{26!}{e}$.

The exact formula is

$$n! \sum_{i=0}^n \frac{(-1)^i}{i!}$$

(which can be [derived with the inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Derivation_by_inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle))

but for $n \ge 1$ you can just round $\frac{n!}{e}$ to the nearest integer.